# disable editing and setItem to several rows in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

`|   Name   |  Math  |  Physics  |  Average grade  |`
`|          |        |           |                 |`
`|          |        |           |                 |`
`|          |        |           |                 |`
`|          |        |           |                 |`
`|          |        |           |                 |`
`|          |        |           |                 |`

1. the column "math" and "physics" is for user to put number in, the column "average" CAN NOT be put value, it is only for showing average value after user put "math" and "physics" grade. How can i disable editing but still show calculated value in column "average" ?
2. I want to write content to several rows, but my code does not work

   ```
   ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);
   ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(8);
   ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
   QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("Hello World"));
   for (int i=0; i< ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
       ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 0, newItem);
   ```

There is a message like this

```
QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget
```

I still don't understand because i am a newbie with QT. Please help me, many thanks ! :)

Code updated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui.tableWidget->rowCount(); i++) {
    QTableWidgetItem *icon_item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    QIcon icon(":/myproject/icon/test.png");
    icon_item->setIcon(icon);
    ui.tableWidget->setItem(i, 0, icon_item);
}

for (int j = 0; j < ui.tableWidget->rowCount(); j++) {
    ui.tableWidget->item(j, 3)->setFlags(ui.tableWidget->item(j, 3)->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can use [`QTableWidgetItem::setFlags()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setFlags). To keep the other default flags, but remove `Qt::ItemIsEditable`:

   ```
   item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
   ```
2. You cannot set the same `QTableWidgetItem` instance to multiple cells. To get you started:

   ```
   for (...) {
       QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(...);
       tableWidget->setItem(...);
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot. Your 2nd solution works well for me. However, the first one does not work because I have access violation.
my code is
`for (int i=0; i<ui.tablewidget->rowCount(); i++) {
   ui.tablewidget->item(i,3)->setFlags(ui.tablewidget->item(i,3)->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
}`

when i debug, when i run to 4, I have access violation :(

Comment: Then you are probably dereferencing a null pointer, because didn't call setItem() for that cell/column.

Comment: so what should i do to avoid this problem ? (sorry, i am a newbie)

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can only guess that you probably created a single item for each row, and called `ui.tablewidget->setItem(i, 0, someItem);`, but forgot to create items for the other colums and call `ui.tablewidget->setItem(i, 3, otherItem);`, for example.

Comment: Ouch, you are right. I updated my code in my question above. Actually I want to create a small icon beside name in the column 0, so I insert the icon in the column 0 only. The column 1 and column 2 should not contain icon, it should be for value only, therefore i did not create any item for that. Column 3 is only for showing, so i code as you suggested. So how can I improve my code to avoid problem with pointer ?

Comment: Just like you create a new item, configure it (set an icon), and set it to column `0` at row `i`. Repeat same steps: create a new item, configure it (set text), but set it to column `3` at row `i`.

Comment: thanks a lot jpnurmi, you helped me a lot ! thank you ! :)